# Creating Notification On A Variable Change

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications

how can I set up my code so that I set up a listener on an integer variable, so that when the value changes (the value is binded to an object), the notification is called?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot detect the change of a plain C variable.

You probably want to observe a change of an object's internal state. If so, you should wrap the integer value into a property and use accessor methods to modify the value.

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@property int bar; // declares a property of type int
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize bar; // creates accessor methods for the property
@end
```

Changes to properties can be detected using [Key Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by "wrap the integer value into a property"? Thanks!

Comment: I have wrapped the integer into a property, creating a new class as you have described above.

Now the problem lies with the KVO. I am creating a new instance of the class in which bar (variable used above) is a property, as follows:

    tabViewIndex *tvi = [[tabViewIndex alloc ] init];
  
    [tvi addObserver:self
    forKeyPath:@"bar"
    options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
    context:NULL ];

Comment: Then, I am calling this method: 

    -(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
    {
     NSLog (@"working");
    }

trying to log when there is a change. However, this method is not being called. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Solved.. had a mixup in the classes. Thanks for your help!